# C++ How to correctly expose a Shared Library via header

Tags: c++, attributes, shared-libraries, header-files, private-members

I've designed and developed a SHARED library and would like to distribute it, but I don't want to expose the private methods and private attributes.

Here is what I have tried with no success:

**Full header, used to build the library mylib.so:**

```
namespace MYNAMESPACE{
    enum class MyReturnCode {
        Success = 1,
        MyRetCode01,
        MyRetCode02
    };
    class MyException {
        public:
            MyException(
                MYNAMESPACE::MyReturnCode _code,
                std::string _message);

            MYNAMESPACE::MyReturnCode code;
            std::string message;
    };
    class MyClass {
        public:     
            MyClass();
            ~MyClass();
            void initialize();
            std::string function01();
            std::string function02(); 
            int attribute01;
            float attribute02;     
        private:
            std::string function03();
            int attribute03;
            float attribute04;
    };
}
```

The header I designed to use when sharing mylib.so with others is similar to this one, but without the private section.

When I call the function `initialize`, the attributes `attribute03` and `attribute04` are correctly set and I can use them until some point.

**THE ACTUAL PROBLEM WITH ALL THIS SCENARIO**

I don't know why, but at some point, `attribute03` and `attribute04` just get some trash and I have a `SIGABRT` that ends the execution.

**EDITED (2nd time)**

After some comments, I went into the following PIMPL solution and now it is working fine.

**header my_class_api.hpp, used to distribute with mylib.so**

```
#include <memory>

namespace MY_API {
    class MyClassAPI {
        public:     
            virtual ~MyClassAPI() {};
            virtual void initialize() = 0;
            virtual std::string function01() = 0;
            virtual std::string function02() = 0; 

            static std::shared_ptr<MyClassAPI> get_my_api();
    };
}
```

**NEW full header my_class.hpp, used to build the library mylib.so:**

```
#include "my_class_api.hpp"

namespace MYNAMESPACE{
    class MyClass : public MY_API::MyClassAPI {
        public:     
            MyClass();
            ~MyClass() override;
            void initialize() override;
            std::string function01() override;
            std::string function02() override; 

        private:
            std::string function03();
            int attribute03;
            float attribute04;
    };
}
```

**Implementation file my_class.cpp**

```
#include "my_class.hpp"

namespace MY_API {

    std::shared_ptr<MyClassAPI> MyClassAPI::get_my_api() {
        return std::make_shared<MYNAMESPACE::MyClass>();
    }
}

namespace MYNAMESPACE {

    MyClass::MyClass() { }
    MyClass::~MyClass() { }
    void MyClass::initialize() { }
    std::string MyClass::function01() { }
    std::string MyClass::function02() { }
}
```

Thanks everybody that helped me! I hope this example helps others too.

Comment: You can use the _Pimpl Idiom_ to hide the private stuff.

Comment: If you leave out the `private` variables from a public header, instancing from "outside" may fail to allocate the correct size for your class. This would explain the `SIGABRT` - memory access to non-allocated memory (as your "inside" constructor assumes memory is allocated properly).

Comment: The Pimpl Idiom seems to be what I need. I don't know how to do it, but I will invest some time searching and studying. Thank you @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Hmm... you are right. Thank you @Scheff

Comment: Debugging construction step by step, I once noticed that first memory is allocated and then the constructor is called. The latter is part of your library but the former is part of some other (e.g. standard library or built-in code for memory allocation). This in addition to what I wrote above. A better solution is already mentioned - the PImpl idiom... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, PIMPL is the best solution for that.  Qt, for example, uses PIMPL on all its classes to also ensure binary compatibility.  That is, when a newer version of a DLL is installed, it is compatible with all old binaries, because the public interface does not change.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl

Answer (score 0):

> The header I designed to use when sharing mylib.so with others is similar to this one, but without the private section.

The header that you use to build the .so shared lib should be the same as the header that you expose to the client. One cannot have private members, and the other not have them. The client will not consider the private members to be part of the class, but when executing a function, it would try to use a memory that does not belong to the instance.

As mentioned, PIMPL is a commonly used solution. In your class's private section you can have a MyClassData* mData; declaration. In your .cpp file, you can define the struct MyClassData, and initiate its members. In the constructor, allocate memory to mData, and in the destructor delete the memory.